# Python 3 tkinter keyboard shortcuts call a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a function that I'm trying to call by pressing two key on the keyboard. Example : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

```
self._first_event = None
self._second_event = None

def function(self, event):
    if self._first_event == None:
        self._first_event = event
    else:
        self._second_event = event
        if self._first_event == 'Ctrl' and self._second_event == 'n':
            return someotherfunction()
```

I tried this code but it doesn't call the someotherfunction()

Comment: please show us how you are making the binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This code** is doing what you are trying to achieve:

```
from tkinter import *

def someotherfunction(e=None):
    print('It works !')

root = Tk()
root.bind('<Control-n>', someotherfunction)
root.mainloop()
```

I think it's a more proper way to to do it than how you were trying to do it. By the way if you look at the [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) of the **event object** it contains multiple things so you can't compare it to a string like so. You should use `event.keysym` for exemple.

**Note:**

`<a>` correspond to <kbd>A</kbd>

`<A>` correspond to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

`<Control-n>` correspond to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

`<Control-N>` correspond to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

Comment: @aitsuri I am glad it helps you :) If it solve your problem you can "accept" the answer to indicate that the question is "solved"

Comment: @aitsuri since I've seen you never accepted answer before I link you [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which explain what is this feature for